# How to add a button or text on slides of a slideshow made in react-gesture-gallery

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a slideshow using `react-gesture-gallery` and `react-gesture-responder`. The code here:

```
    import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import { Gallery, GalleryImage } from "react-gesture-gallery";

    const images = [
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559666126-84f389727b9a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1356&q=80",
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557389352-e721da78ad9f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80",
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553969420-fb915228af51?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1049&q=80",
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550596334-7bb40a71b6bc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80",
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550640964-4775934de4af?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80"
    ];

    function App() {
      const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

      React.useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          if (index == images.length - 1) {
            setIndex(0);
          } else {
            setIndex(prevVal => prevVal + 1);
          }
        }, 2500);

        return () => clearInterval(interval);
      });

      return (
        <Gallery
          style={{
            height: "100vh",
            width: "100vw",
            backgroundColor: "#0a0a0a"
          }}
          index={index}
          onRequestChange={i => {
            setIndex(i);
          }}
        >
          {images.map(img => (
            <GalleryImage src={img} objectFit={"contain"} />
          ))}
        </Gallery>
      );
    }

    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

the code is vailable [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/final-image-gallery-hw6ic).

I would like to add some html in every single slide. For instance, a short description about that slide and a button.

[image]

And I am new in react. Do you recommend other libraries to make slideshow and image galleries in react?

Any one please? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return the html content inside the map function.

```
{images.map(image => (
  <div>
    <GalleryImage objectFit="contain" key={image} src={image} />
    <h1 className="description">Description here</h1>
  </div>
))}
```

if you want the description to appear on top of the image use `position: absolute` with margin top.

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/final-image-gallery-jzw6s?fontsize=14)

Comment: this is nice one, but description will be the same for all of the images. Every single Image has their own description

Comment: this's just an example, change the description to what you want.

Comment: I don't know how to do this. Can you help me add separate descriptions for each slides ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing writing issues on the slides then you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slick for the same.